# coding bat ap-1 scoresIncreasing

Tags: java

Given an array of scores, return true if each score is equal or greater than the one before. The array will be length 2 or more.

```
             scoresIncreasing([1, 3, 4]) → true
             scoresIncreasing([1, 3, 2]) → false
             scoresIncreasing([1, 1, 4]) → true
```

my solution

```
public boolean scoresIncreasing(int[] scores) {
  for (int i = 1; i < scores.length; i++){
      if (scores[i] >= scores[i - 1]) return true;

  }
     return false;
 }
```

Can you please explain why it does not work?

Comment: change this --> `if (scores[i] >= scores[i - 1]) return true;` to this --> `if (scores[i] < scores[i - 1]) return false;` then at the end do `return true`. for more info see the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning as soon as you find an "increasing" score without handling the possibility that there may be a decreasing score later in the array (like in the second test case 3 > 1 so return true, but then 2 < 3 so it should be false).

I'm not posting correct code because this looks like homework.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw Either way, it's an exercise so giving a full answer doesn't sit well with me. I think pointing out the flaw and letting OP fix it is better than stealing their chance to do it themselves.

Comment: definitely agree ^^.